# How to show all cards again after clicking on a back button inside the card that has been opened

Tags: jquery

I have a view with a list of cards. If a user clicks on a card, the other cards should hide. Once the clicked card expands, there is a back button that will show all the other cards.

the problem I have is that the back button is inside the 'j-card' class and therefore triggers that first piece of the code.

```
<div class="card stack-card j-card ">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" style="">Activity 1</h5>
        <div class="j-measurements">
            <div class="card--label"><span>Time: 10 min</span></div>
            <div class="card--label"><span>Start: 8:45</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn j-btn" style="display: none;">Back</div>
    </div>  
</div>


<div class="card stack-card j-card" >
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Activity 2</h5>


        <div class="j-measurements">

            <div class="card--label"><span>Time: 10 min</span></div>
            <div class="card--label"><span>Start: 8:45</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn j-btn" style="display: none;">Back</div>

    </div>  
</div>

<div class="card stack-card j-card" >
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Activity3</h5>


        <div class="j-measurements">

            <div class="card--label"><span>Time: 10 min</span></div>
            <div class="card--label"><span>Start: 8:45</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn j-btn" style="display: none;">Back</div>
    </div>  
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $().ready(function(){ 

        $('.j-card').on('click', function(e) {
            $('.j-card').not(this).slideUp('fast');
            $('.j-measurements').slideUp('fast');
            $('.j-btn', this).toggle();
        });

        $('.j-btn').on('click', function(e) {
            $('.j-card').show();
        });
    });

</script>
```

The user should see a list of cards. The user can click on a card, the card will show more info and a back/close button, the other cards will be hidden. Once clicked the card will become like the other cards, and the other cards will show up again.

Comment: You should add a class like `active` when you are showing more info for a card. If a card has the class `active` then all siblings should hide, if it doesn't, then show all of the siblings. So when clicking the back/close button, remove the active class and show siblings.

Comment: '''
 $().ready(function(){ 

  $('.j-card').on('click', function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.j-card').toggle();
   $('.j-btn', this).show();
  });
  
  $('.j-btn').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).siblings('.j-card').show();
  });
 });
'''